# The Help Center claims that moderators have no abilities

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, help-center

Screenshot (click to enlarge):

[image: screenshot]

I was browsing the Help Center of PPCG when I found this "Moderator Abilities" tab. When I clicked it, [the page was completely blank](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/mods).

... does this mean that moderators no longer have any abilities? Eeeek!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a new, moderator only, section of the help center.

There are no help articles defined for it yet.

They will come, in time. Hopefully soon.

---

There are a few articles in the pipeline ready to be published.

You (moderators) will be seeing them starting tomorrow, you know, [because](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: There are two already out, but they're not pushed out from MSE yet, as it were.

Comment: You mean.. you.. you.. TOOK OUR ABILITIES? HOW COULD YOU! D:

Comment: @ɥʇǝS - if you behave yourselves, we will start giving them back. Slowly.

Comment: Then, apparently, we are doomed! ;) /cc @ɥʇǝS

Comment: OK, all moderators can thank @Andrew'saUnitato for the collective punishment.